# How to call a public function from another template in magento\module-catalog

Tags: catalog-price-rules, magento-2.1

i need to add div's in case of products special price in magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml

I'm ovverriding that file in my theme.

I may use e.g., to check for a special price, the same method used in magento\module-catalog\view\base\templates\product\price\final_price.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

but I don't know how to call it because of different $block. How can i do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. (How we can call any block function in any phtml?)

For ex your block class is

```
<?php
namespace Company\Helloworld\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Main extends Template
{
    public function getMyCustomMethod()
    {
        return '<b>MyCustomMethod</b>';
    }
}
```

then in any phtml file you can use following code to get method of this block.

```
<?php
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Helloworld\Block\Main');
echo $blockObj->getMyCustomMethod();
?>
```